# How to link css file in jsp pages

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, bootstrap-4

My Directory [Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcDuu.jpg)

i am new in JSP and trying to link bootstrap.min.css file which is located in bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css with the header file Header.jsp which is located in Parts/Header.jsp

this is my code **Header.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<jsp:include page ="Parts/Header.jsp"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid relative paths you must start your URL with a / prefixed by te context root of your application.

Then change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

By:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
     <%@ include file="style.css"%>
</style>
```